# Error "TF255115: The following service did not start: TfsJobAgent." while starting Azure DevOPs Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

I have just installed  Azure DevOPs Server 2019 and am running Server Configuration Wizard.

I am getting error "TF255115: The following service did not start: TfsJobAgent".

Here is what I see in the event log:

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19671, time stamp: 0x5e673d0b
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00000000000088dc
Faulting process id: 0x292c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d617e3f41741be
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019\Application Tier\TfsJobAgent\TfsJobAgent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 31ebbfa5-83d7-11ea-810c-000d3ab2ccc5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I have found two posts regarding error TF255115:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75c370fe-7951-44e9-85be-c7d2378f7beb/cannot-start-service-tfsjobagent-on-computer-ltcomputernamegt?forum=tfssetup

This post recommends to check whether USERS group has Read and Execute permissions for file TFSJobAgent.exe. I have checked it and indeed it has.

2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fb2762c-7633-4cb0-9640-a4ded2deddcf/tfs2010-trail-version-configuration-issues-in-win7x64?forum=tfssetup

This post recommends to check  whether I have permissions to run `Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent` service. However, I don't find such a service. Since the above post was written, 8 years ago, TFS was renamed to Azure, so I looked also for Azure-related services, but found nothing.

Please assist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Azure DevOps Server 2019. Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent service has renamed to  **Azure DevOps Server Background Job Agent**.

According to the error info, you need to make sure this service is running in your service list of your server.

[image]

Comment: There is no such service,  Azure DevOps Server Background Job Agent, in the service list.

Comment: @AlexKarnovsky **There should be**. If so,  since you have just installed Azure DevOps Server 2019.  I am afraid, you may not installed correctly. Please try to uninstall and re-install  your entire Azure DevOps Server or  application tier. Which may do the trick.

Comment: I reinstalled the Azure DevOps Server 2019, and now the Configuration Wizard completed successfully. Thank you very much!